# mobile app dev - how to create crossplatform app with automatic file download with access to mobile file system? (sample code?)

Tags: android, mobile, filesystems, windows-mobile

I need to create some kind of automatic file downloader (for a specific website - over HTTP or HTTPS) which is able to place the downloaded files in a directory on the mobile which can accessed e.g. bei media players (to play mp3 files) or other software (e.g. to open pdf files). In other words: Which have "file-system-access" on the mobile.

It should be crossplattform, so I should be able to create a native app (and distribute it via the respective app-stores) of (must-have) Android, iOS, Windows Phone and (nice-to-have) the "other" plattforms like blackberry and so on.

It would be great if someone could post some lines of sample-code or link to small sample apps.

PS: It would be nice if the SMS-inbox could be read, but that's (nice-to-have), too.

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to be able to do this as cross platform.

Win Phone, Android, and iOS are completely different operating systems.

You are going to need 3 different software tools for developing your application (Visual Studio and the other 2), and you are going to have to have and maintain 3 different installs.